# Adding users to a website and redirecting each user to their own page

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I am trying to set up a client portion of a website. Ideally, when the client clicks the client log in button they will be prompted for a username and password and then will be redirected to a simple list of files residing in the username folder.

The server has mySQL and PHP on it, and I've found plenty of tutorials and templates for PHP login systems, but most of them are overkill for what I am trying to do and don't provide me with the knowledge to handle the redirecting.

The username and password will be assigned to clients by me, so there isn't any registration

I have a mySQL database set up with the client information, I'm just not sure what I need to do with PHP to protect the client folders and accept a client login and redirect them to their specific folder.

EDIT: I am sorry that the question is a bit broad, the best I can do is, what would the PHP code be in a client log in page to take the credentials (username, password), run them against a mySQL database, and then redirect to a private folder (username).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at the help section regarding [how to ask a on-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). At the moment, your question appears to be too broad as there is no indication of *specifically* what you have tried, or what you are considering "overkill" for user authentication (in other words, no way of providing you a reasonable, targeted answer.)

Comment: This is not a question. it is a to-do list, and we are not here to do your job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this yourself. But most likely this will result in error prone sub par implementation since you are trying this for the first time. Did you look at something like https://pyd.io/? You can point this to directories and assign users and directories (which can be private).

Comment: Pydio looks like it would be able to handle everything we wanted excellently, but our webpage is being hosted externally and I don't believe Pydio would work with it. I will keep it in mind though for the future.

Comment: I do use pydio in many of my shared hosting accounts to access the files. So I don't see why it won't work for your use case.

Comment: Excellent, I had thought Pydio ran it's own server. This should work.

Comment: The install is telling me I am missing Mcrypt, but I am not sure how to install that on the hosted server. Any tips?